# Multiple components decide to fetch an object at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, dispatch

I have a React component that somehow looks like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); // Redux dispatch function
    const isLoading = useSelector(selIsLoading); // flag from our Redux app state
    const data = useSelector(selData); // data from our Redux app state

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!data && !isLoading) {
            console.log('Need to fetch!');
            dispatch(actionToFetchStuff());
        }
    }, [data, isLoading]);

    return !data ? <NoData /> : <Data data={data} ...props />;
}
```

The problem is: When there are multiple instances of `MyComponent` on the page that load simultaneously, the closure of `useEffect` has captured the *initial* values of `isLoading` and `data`. That's why all components come to the conclusion that they need to fetch the object at the same time. The `isLoading` flag that should prevent this appears later, because `dispatch` (or rather, the effect of `useEffect`) is (pseudo-) asynchronous.

I could use a `saga`, but I'd rather not, because this is such a simple component, and sagas tend to make things complicated. I'm looking for a clever way with React hooks or something similar that doesn't make my component overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a hook that solves the problem for me. My component becomes:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [data, isLoading] = useRemoteData(props, () => ({
        isLoading: selIsLoading,
        select: selData,
        shouldFetch: (_state, _props, extras) => 
            !extras.selected && !extras.isLoading,
        fetch: dispatch => dispatch(actionToFetchStuff()),
    }));
    return !data ? <NoData /> : <Data data={data} />;
}
```

I implemented `useRemoteData` like this: It simply measures the time since the last fetch. If the time is shorter than some minimum delay, it postpones the call to `shouldFetch` until later. This will also make fetching data a bit more sequential, which may lead to a slight increase in overall loading time, but I find it's not a big issue with a maximum delay of 100ms between fetches.

```
const MIN_MILLIS_BETWEEN_FETCHES = 100;

interface RemoteDataExtras<S> {
    selected: S;
    isLoading: boolean;
}

interface RemoteDataOptions<P, S> {
    isLoading: (state: any, props: P) => boolean;
    select: (state: any, props: P) => S;
    shouldFetch: (state: any, props: P, extras: RemoteDataExtras<S>) => boolean;
    fetch: (dispatch: Dispatch<any>, state: any, props: P, extras: RemoteDataExtras<S>) => void;
}

const shared = { lastFetchMillis: 0 };

export function useRemoteData<P, S = unknown>(
    props: P,
    getOptions: () => RemoteDataOptions<P, S>
): [S, boolean, () => void] {
    const staticData = useRef({ timerId: -1 });
    const options = useMemo(getOptions, []);
    const state = useSelector(state => state);
    const [_, setRetryTime] = useState(0);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const extras: RemoteDataExtras<S> = {
        selected: options.select(state, props),
        isLoading: options.isLoading(state, props),
    };

    const shouldFetch = () => {
        if (Date.now() - shared.lastFetchMillis < MIN_MILLIS_BETWEEN_FETCHES) {
            // The last fetch is too recent ago. Doing another fetch right now can
            // lead to major overfetching or even endless loops, because our
            // isLoading may not have updated yet due to the asynchronous way how
            // dispatch works. We return false here, but we add a timer to remind
            // us later.

            if (staticData.current.timerId >= 0) {
                window.clearTimeout(staticData.current.timerId);
            }

            const delay = MIN_MILLIS_BETWEEN_FETCHES -
                (Date.now() - shared.lastFetchMillis);

            staticData.current.timerId = window.setTimeout(() => {
                setRetryTime(Date.now()); // this will force a re-render, leading to a re-evaluation of shouldFetch
            }, delay);

            return false;
        } else {
            return options.shouldFetch(state, props, extras);
        }
    };

    const fetch = () => {
        options.fetch(dispatch, state, props, extras);
        shared.lastFetchMillis = Date.now();
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (shouldFetch()) {
                fetch();
            }
        },
        undefined // i.e. on each update
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if (staticData.current.timerId >= 0) {
                window.clearTimeout(staticData.current.timerId);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    return [extras.selected, extras.isLoading, fetch];
}
```